# Are there spaces between rules of the tables, how can I delete them?

Tags: tables, spacing, rules

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

% \usepackage{geometry}
%  \geometry{
%  a4paper,
%  total={210mm,297mm},
%  left=20mm,
%  right=20mm,
%  top=20mm,
%  bottom=20mm,
%  }
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{showkeys}
% \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% per le figure:
\usepackage{graphicx}
% per il testo attorno alle figure
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
% usare colori in tabella:
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%tabelle lunghe (gestione oltre il margine)
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
% \usepackage{lmode rn}
% \usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage[usenames]{color}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{xspace}
% \lstset{language=TeX,
%       backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
%       basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
%       xleftmargin=3em}

\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt}
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\#1}{}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\cfoot{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}
{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}
{\bfseries\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\begin {flushright}
Dedica
\end {flushright}

\tableofcontents

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{4 cm}|m{4.5 cm}|m{3 cm}|}
\rowcolor{orange}
\rule[1ex]{0ex}{3ex}
Entità&Significato&Attributi&Identificatori \\
\midrule
Utente&
Utente finale registrato al servizio&
\begin{description}
 \item{} Username - Stringa  
 \item{} Password - Stringa 
 \item{} Nome - Stringa  
 \item{} Cognome - Stringa 
 \item{} DataNascita - Data 
 \item{}  PayPal - Stringa 
 \item{} IndirizzoDomicilio - Stringa 
\end{description}
&
Username \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella Entità}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Which rules? The vertical ones? Yes, there usually **is** space of width `\tabcolsep` (6pt usually by default). Or do you mean the `horizontal` rules -- that's a feature of `booktabs` package. If really needed, the spacings can be changed by setting `\belowrulesep` and `\aboverulesep`

Comment: Simply don't use vertical rules along with commands of `booktabs` such as `\toprule`, `\bottomrule` and `\midrule`. Better, never use vertical rules in tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are separations above and below the horizontal rules if the `booktabs` package is included -- this is a nice design feature of that package!

If it is really necessary: (However, this makes the use of `booktabs` basically useless!)

The spacings above and below a horizontal rule made by `\toprule`, `\bottomrule`, `midrule` and `\cmidrule` (all provided by `booktabs` package) can be controlled with the lengths

`\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`. Setting them both to `0pt` will cause the separation to vanish:

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
```

I've done this within the `table` environment to restrict the change to the current table, not globally.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% per il testo attorno alle figure
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
% usare colori in tabella:
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%tabelle lunghe (gestione oltre il margine)
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{ltablex}

\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt}
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\#1}{}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\cfoot{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}
{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}
{\bfseries\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\begin {flushright}
Dedica
\end {flushright}

\tableofcontents

\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\centering\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{4 cm}|m{4.5 cm}|m{3 cm}|}
\rowcolor{orange}
\rule[1ex]{0ex}{3ex} %%%% Why???? Why not \toprule with other thickness?
Entità&Significato&Attributi&Identificatori \\
\midrule
Utente&
Utente finale registrato al servizio&
\begin{description}
 \item{} Username - Stringa  
 \item{} Password - Stringa 
 \item{} Nome - Stringa  
 \item{} Cognome - Stringa 
 \item{} DataNascita - Data 
 \item{}  PayPal - Stringa 
 \item{} IndirizzoDomicilio - Stringa 
\end{description}
&
Username \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella Entità}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are other design issues not being addressed with my answer. I've deleted some commented code out of the 'MWE' ;-)